# Why image's resolution from Camera.PictureCallback() is the size of PreviewSize?

Tags: android, camera, size, image

I'm trying to use Android Camera API but when I take a picture, it's resolution is the same as my Camera object previewSize resolution.

Some code for explain:

```
private Camera mCamera;
private Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback;

...
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
...
Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight);
        p.setPictureSize(mPictureWidth,mPictureHeight);
mCamera.setParameters(p);
...
}

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
                Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
                bitmapPicture.getWidth(); //At this point the width is the same as mPreviewWidth and I want it to be mPictureWidth
}
/**
* This function is called when the user touches the surfaceview
*/
public void clickCamera(View v){
        mCamera.takePicture(null, mPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);
    }
```

How I said at the commented line, instead previewSize I want to take a picture with the pictureSize configured to my Camera

Comment: might be bcoz of the width and height you set here,
 p.setPictureSize(mPictureWidth,mPictureHeight);

Comment: @AndroSelva those values are correct, both of them represent the resolution that I want to configure. After some time debugging I discovered what was wrong, I'll write the answer here asap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, after spending some time debugging I've discovered what was wrong.

The point is, you only can set the picturesize if your previewsize is compatible with it. By compatible I mean that the aspec ratio (width to height ratio) of their resolution is the same.

### Example :

A wide-screen previewsize resolution only supports wide-screen picturesize resolution.

If you put a wrong resolution for a previewsize ( wide-screen previewsize with normal-screen picturesize ) then the picturesize will not be correctly set.

I've created an example of supportedPreviewSize vs supportedPictureSize

```
preview 800 x 600
    2048 x 1536 [ ok ]
    1600 x 1200 [ ok ]
    800  x 600  [ ok ]
    2048 x 1232 [ fail - 2048 x 1536 ]
    1600 x 960  [ fail - 1600 x 1200 ]
    1024 x 600  [ fail - 1600 x 1200 ]
    
preview 1024 x 600
    2048 x 1536 [ fail - 2048 x 1232 ]
    1600 x 1200 [ fail - 2048 x 1232 ]
    800  x 600  [ fail - 1024 x 600  ]
    2048 x 1232 [ ok ]
    1600 x 960  [ ok ]
    1024 x 600  [ ok ]
```

I hope that this will help somebody who has the same problem in the future.